# Java Matcher.appendReplacement() and Matcher.appendTail() for StringBuilder?

Tags: java

Is there an alternative to Matcher.appendReplacement() and Matcher.appendTail() which takes StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer ?

Is there an 'easy' way to 'convert' Java code which calls Matcher with a StringBuffer to use StringBuilder instead?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 9):

Short answer, not yet. Not until Java 9. In Java 9 there are `Matcher.appendReplacement(StringBuilder,String)` and `Matcher.appendTail(StringBuilder)` methods added to the [API](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuilder-java.lang.String-).

Until then if you don't need group substitutions in replacement string then I still find this solution 'easy':

```
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(s);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int pos = 0;
while(m.find()) {
    sb.append(s, pos, m.start());
    pos = m.end();
    sb.append("replacement")
}
sb.append(s, pos, s.length());
```

And even if you need group subtitutions then it gets just 'moderately' difficult:

```
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(s);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int pos = 0;
while(m.find()) {
    sb.append(s, pos, m.start());
    pos = m.end();
    if (m.start(1) >= 0) {                  // check if group 1 matched
        sb.append(s, m.start(1), m.end(1)); // replace with group 1
    }
}
sb.append(s, pos, s.length());
```

Comment: Cripes: Have you seen the code for `Matcher.appendReplacement()`!?  Incredible it is so complex.

Comment: For short strings you might as well take the memory hit and use `String`.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, no.

This is as per [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) in latest Java 8 at the time of writing.

However, one of the overloaded `StringBuffer` constructors takes a `CharSequence` as parameter, and `StringBuilder` (just like `StringBuffer`) IS-A `CharSequence`.

For instance:

```
matcher.appendReplacement(
    new StringBuffer(yourOriginalStringBuilder), "yourReplacement"
);
```

**Edit**

Since Java 9, an overload is available, which takes a `StringBuilder` instead - see API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuilder-java.lang.String-).

Comment: One of reason to not use StringBuffer is to avoid thread synchronization. And since StringBuffer is synchronized, your code actually synchronizes on more objects.
And anyway it just doesn't work, since StringBuffer does not work anymore on StringBuilder passed to its constructor and appendReplacement appends to... nothing.

Comment: @krzychek my answer is old (2016) and predates Java 9, where indeed there is an overload taking `StringBuilder` - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuilder-java.lang.String-). Regardless, the risk of blocking while using the older method signature is minimal, as you would have to invoke `appendReplacement` on the same `StringBuffer` across multiple threads, which implies bad design in the first place.

Comment: "the risk of blocking while using the older method signature is minimal". Synchronization is the main thing that differs Buffer from Builder and it exist apart from being invoked on a single thread. And if concurrent access is needed synchronization should be introduced apart from blocking threat (or solution redesigned).

Comment: Anyway, JIT compiler makes synchronization impact in most cases negligible and the main problem I've seen is that after new StringBuffer(builder) call, matcher is not mutating builder instance anymore, which could be misleading for Java newcomers. (and I've edited example)

Answer (score 0):

So, for readers: full code for JDK 9 and multiple replacement (e.g.
"Hello ${name}, check ${email}"):

```
private static final Pattern PLACEHOLDER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\w+)}");

Matcher matcher = PLACEHOLDER_PATTERN.matcher(value)
if(matcher.find()){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (p.matcher.find()) {
       String key = p.matcher.group(1);
       Object obj = getObject(key, map);
       p.matcher.appendReplacement(sb, obj.toString());
    }
    p.matcher.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString;
}
```